# Reading and formatting events from Windows Event Log

Tags: java, windows, jna, event-log

The following code reads and prints the events from the `Windows Event Log` of the local computer.

```
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.Date;

import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Advapi32Util.EventLogIterator;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Advapi32Util.EventLogRecord;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinNT;

public class EventLog {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        EventLogIterator iter = new EventLogIterator(null, "Application", WinNT.EVENTLOG_FORWARDS_READ);
        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            EventLogRecord record = iter.next();
            if (record.getData() == null) {
                continue;
            }
            Date eventTime = new Date(record.getRecord().TimeGenerated.longValue() * 1000L);
            String data = new String(record.getData(), "windows-1252");
            System.out.println(record.getRecordNumber() + " Event Time: " + eventTime + //
                               ": Event ID: " + record.getInstanceId() + //
                               ", Event Type: " + record.getType() + //
                               ", Event Data: " + data + //
                               ", Event Source: " + record.getSource());
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that the event `data` is present as `byte` array (`byte[]`) but I need proper formatted text. I tried to transform this `data` into a `String` by using different encodings but none of them produced the expected result.

```
String data = new String(record.getData(), "windows-1252");
```

How can the event `data` be transformed into human readable text?

Comment: Windows often uses some species of UTF-16. Did you try that? Also, why JNA - why not parse Powershell `Get-EventLog`?

Comment: Thanks `g00se`, using Powershell `Get-EventLog` is an interesting approach. Unless I don't find another solution, I'll try to invoke it from my Java program and parse the printed events programmatically.

Comment: Provide examples of event log and expected/actual results.

Comment: What happened with `getStrings()` btw?

Comment: @g00se: In some cases, `getStrings()` does not provide any data, in some other cases the data is incomplete and doesn't match the one that can be seen in the `Windows Event Viewer`.  I see however that this is the case when the `Event ID` is also present (`!= 0`). Therefore, I believe that the `Event Viewer` uses this `Event ID` to do some lookup to retrieve the event description. I now voted to undelete the answer from `aled` as it seems to be the correct answer to my question. As soon as it becomes editable again, I will accept it.

Comment: `@Daniel Widdis`:  The answer you are referencing requires elevated or shared access to the .evtx log files. For my case, this is unfortunately not an option to go with.

Comment: @uminder understood. It's been a while since I had access to Windows but IIRC the binary data wasn't easily translated to human readable text.